# Page Not Found on Wordpress Installation

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation which i installed long time ago and since then it was working  fine, but today when i am going to the site it's showing "OOPS!! Page Not Found Page" (please check site slimmerexpert.co.uk), this site is hosted on Godaddy.

I didn't do anything recently on this installation, i even removed a few plugins that i installed recently through FTP, but the error remains the same.

Also please help me to figure out what needs to be done in case it cant be repaired.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the domain is pointing to the right FTP folder? For example, forget about WordPress for a minute... can you pull up a simple image?

Comment: i checked DNS, its showing the correct IP and im able to pull up images etc from that folder, i would request you to plz check the domain once, because this is weird, it never happened, i would never mess with DNS settings, not with this domain

Comment: do you still have an `index.php` file in the root? How about an `.htaccess` file?

Comment: yes i still have those files there

Answer (score 1):

If you already checked your plugins, then revisit your permalinks via the image below.
[image]
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/page-not-found-on-changing-permalinks-setting

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/postname-permalinks-cause-page-not-found-after-auto-update-to-381

Comment: thnx for reply...but it was a godaddy problem, everything was fine from my side

Answer (score 0):

You are opening logs apache (example for ubuntu /var/logs/apache2/) and simple will find problems.